# Disable autoselect in AutoCompleteBox

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

I am creating an application on Windows Phone 7 using AutoCompleteBox.

There are three words in it:

- AM
- Amplitude
- Amplifier

When I type am, it automatically selects AM. Rather, it should show me these 3 options to select.

How can I disable autoselect?

Answer (score 0):

This is a reported, and by the looks of it, unresolved issue:

http://silverlight.codeplex.com/workitem/9558